# Jquery to update price in hidden form field

Tags: jquery

I have a online store and on the product pages, I need the option dropdown menu to change the product base price ($500) and add the added option price ($100) in 2 places:

1. Displayed to the user (currently working)
2. Hidden form field (not working/unsure how to accomplish)

So far I have #1 working, but not number #2. I'd like to pass the Base Price ($500) + Added Option Price ($100) = $600 to the hidden form field so I can submit that field to be processed on another page. Here’s what I have:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>

<script>
   $(window).load(function(){
   $("select").change(function(){
       var price = parseFloat($(this).find("option:selected").data("price"));

       if(isNaN(price))
           price = 0;

       var currPrice = parseFloat($("span").data("price"));
       $("span").text(currPrice + price);
    })
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>

<select name="productoption">
   <option data-price="" value="XL" selected="selected">XL</option>
   <option data-price="" value="2XL">2XL</option>
   <option data-price="100" value="3XL">3XL [Add $100]</option>
</select>

<p>Price - $<span data-price="500">500</span></p>

<form action="" name="myForm" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="price" value="" />
      <input type="submit" name="addcart" value="Add To Cart" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

If there is a easier way to accomplish this, I'm all ears.

Comment: `$("input[name=price]").val(currPrice + price);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the `value` of `hidden` field with name `'price'` use:

```
$("input[name=price]").val(currPrice + price);
```